# Create a file in linux

Tags: c++

I'm new in linux, I'd like to create a file and write something into.

I don't get any error, but the code doesn't create any file...what am I missing?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main(){
    std::ofstream out("/Home/peter/Dropbox/C++/linux/data.dat", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
    if(!out)
        std::cout << " File isn't open\n" << std::endl;
    char s = 'a';

    for(int i = 0; i<100; i++)
        out.put(s);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: It's `/home/...` not `/Home/...`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should add `out.close()` to the end of your program.  This will flush the write buffer to ensure that it was properly written to.

Also, confirm that you actually have (rather, that your program has) permission to create and write files in that directory.

Finally, make sure the path you're writing to is actually correct.  As @Adam pointed out in a comment, you probably meant to use `/home/...` and not `/Home/...`

Comment: Uhhhh, the uppercase was the problem! Thanks! :)

Comment: `close` will make sure that the stream is flushed, but the file is actually created on open.

Answer (score 2):

I copied and pasted the script, but changed the path, and the code executed successfully. I recommend using `out.close()` after you are done with the file to close the stream.

You could also use stream operators on the file to write it:

```
for( int i = 0; i < 100; i++ )
  out << s;
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `out.put(s);` to `out << s;`

Secondly once you are done working with files and streams, it is a good practice to close them. It prevents unwanted memory leaks. so put `out.close()` before return or when you are done working with file.